# mysql two FK in the same table

Tags: mysql, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have three tables: A, B, C. Table C has two FKs which points to A id and B id.

When I try to insert something inside C, if I fill the FK column which points to A with a valid ID and let the FK for B table empty or null or zero, MYSQL throws and error saying that I have another FK to fill.

What is the best solution for this problem?

I was thinking that it would be OK to have two C tables, one for A and the other one for B: C_A, C_B with only one FK in each of them.

I have to consider that I am using also Hibernate JPA and the solution I have will work fine. But this will mean one extra table with the same role.

What is your opinion about this problem?

Comment: FKs can be null *if they are configured to allow nulls*. Actually posting the FULL definition of your table is required, otherwise people have to guess

Answer (score 1):

After I read the commend Neil Stockton gave me, I have noticed that on those FKs columns I had set a default value of "0". This is the reason why, even if I have entered NULL for one of FKs, it threw the error.

```
CREATE TABLE `C` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `A_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `B_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  ...
)
```

Solution

```
CREATE TABLE `C` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `A_id` int(11),
  `B_id` int(11),
  ...
)
```